# password_auth.py mushroom cloud error on Airflow webserver open when switching backend DBs

Tags: airflow

Trying to transition from sqlite db to postgresql (based on the guide here: https://www.ryanmerlin.com/2019/07/apache-airflow-installation-on-ubuntu-18-04-18-10/  ) and getting mushroom cloud error at initial screen of webserver UI.

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  ...
  ...
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/utils.py", line 93, in is_accessible
    (not current_user.is_anonymous and current_user.is_superuser())
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/auth/backends/password_auth.py", line 114, in is_superuser
    return hasattr(self, 'user') and self.user.is_superuser()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_superuser'
```

Looking at the webserver logs does not reveal much...

```sh
[airflow@airflowetl airflow]$ tail airflow-webserver.*
==> airflow-webserver.err <==
/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)

==> airflow-webserver.log <==

==> airflow-webserver.out <==
[2019-12-18 10:20:36,553] {settings.py:213} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, max_overflow=10, pool_recycle=1800, pid=72725

==> airflow-webserver.pid <==
72745
```

One thing that may be useful to note (since this appears to be due to some kind of password issue) is that before trying to switch to postgres, I had set bycrpt password according to the docs (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/security.html#password) with the script here:

```py
import airflow
from airflow import models, settings
from airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth import PasswordUser

user = PasswordUser(models.User())
user.username = 'airflow'
user.email = 'myemail@co.org'
user.password = 'mypasword'

session = settings.Session()
session.add(user)
session.commit()
session.close()
exit()
```

Anyone know what could be going on here or how to debug further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rerunning my user/password script fixed the problem.

I assume this is connected to the change to the new postgres server from the previously used sqllite db. I guess this is stored somewhere in the airflow backend DB (rather new to airflow, so was not aware of these internals) and since I am switching backends the new backend does not have this user/auth info and need to rerun the script to import the airflow package and write a new user/password to its backend to be able to log in with password (since my `airflow.cfg` uses `auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth`).